# iOS in-app purchase restoring wrong transaction

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase, storekit

I successfully integrated in-app purchases in my app, but I'm in trouble with the Restore Purchases process.

Yesterday, while testing the in-app purchase process, the app crashed. The crash happened after the tap on the "buy" button, but before the password prompt request from Apple. Since that crash, every time i click "Restore purchases" the app "thinks" I did the purchase before and unlocks the content! (**NEVER** purchased that item before, tested on several devices...)

I checked my recent transactions on my account and it is **NOT** listed.

Here is a slice of the code I use in order to check if user did the purchase the item before:

In `paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished(queue: SKPaymentQueue)` I loop for

```
for transaction in queue.transactions {

    if let pid = transaction.originalTransaction?.payment.productIdentifier {
         ...
    }
}
```

The problem is that `pid` contains the ID of my in-app purchase, so the app goes through the rest of code and unlocks the contents...

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Small update: I released a new version in order to fix the cause of the app crash (nothing related with the in-app purchase process) and now, when I click "restore purchases" in the new version, the app **DOES NOT** restore the purchases (which is the right way to work!). Really strange...

Comment: Did this happen only during testing or in the live app also ? I'm facing the same issue and I'm not  sure whether the app should be released or not.

Comment: @Tobio it happens both during testing and live... After an App Update on the App Store, it seems that now everything is working as should (but I have no idea why!)